# Supporting both interfaces and classes in generic iterable

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to write an interface that is iterable and supports multiple levels of abstraction. I'm having trouble correctly defining the interface.

I've declared the following interfaces and classes (a toy example):

```
public interface A {}

public class B implements A {}

public interface C <T extends A> extends Iterable<T> {}

public class D implements C<B> {
    public Iterator<B> iterator() { ... }
}
```

The following works:

```
D d = new D();
for (A a : d) {}
for (B b : d) {}
```

But the following does not compile. Java says the for-each loop variable should be of type Object.

```
C c = new D();
for (B b : c) {}
```

I know I can cast to appease the compiler in the second example, but that seems yucky. Is there any way to declare interface C and subclass D so that I can support both iteration scenarios, or is that not possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the raw form of the `C` interface when you assign the new `D` to `c`.  Using the raw form of the interface forces type erasure on everything in the interface, meaning that the `Iterator` returned in the foreach loop returns `Object`s, not `B`s.

But `C` takes a type argument that must still be supplied, even if `D` isn't itself generic.  Try

```
C<B> c = new D();
```

Comment: Aha! Somehow the fact that C's type parameter required a subclass of B made me overlook that. It's totally clear now that you pointed it out. Thank you!